# PHP Array_search won't find an existing value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use array_search on a simple array :

```
        echo "<br> Search for : -".ucfirst(strtolower(trim($rowData[0][2]))).'-';
```

here is the index of the value ( I know it but I want PHP to find it for me >< ):

```
        echo '<br>-'.$listMetiers[0].'-';
```

Here is the full array :

```
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($listMetiers);
        echo '</pre>';

        $id_metier = array_search(ucfirst(strtolower(trim($rowData[0][2]))),$listMetiers);

        if(!$id_metier)
        {
          echo ' NOT FOUND !<br>';
          $id_metier = -666;
        }
        else
        {
          echo 'GOOD : '.$id_metier.'<br>';
        }
```

The value is in the array but array_search don't find it ! Look what I have when executing this code :

[image]

What is going on ?

Comment: Your found index is `0` and `!0` is == `TRUE`, so it enters the if statement; Check if `$id_metier` is equals FALSE or not

Comment: OMG thanks ! Haha why I didn't saw that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_searh` is returning 0, and PHP is treating that as a falsy value.

You should change this

```
!$id_metier
```

into this

```
$id_metier === false
```

Comment: correct, but the op wants to check if it doesn't exist, so `=== false`

Comment: Yup @Rizier123 commented on this ! :) That's it but better change into `$id_metier === false` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your test is wong, use:

```
if($id_metier < 0){ // not found
// ...
} else {            // found
// ...
}
```